# What Cipher Suite in this list is the worst to use

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher

I have a list of cipher suites I captured using Wireshark. Which one of these cipher suites would possibly be the worst to use. Here is the list.

[image: List of Cipher Suites]

In my opinion, I choose the:

> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

to be the worst because it uses a 128 bit key and uses CBC instead of GCM cipher mode. Is there any cipher suite that would be less secure here compared to others in the list?

Comment: I would very much expect the answer to be "the last, `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`".

Comment: TLS 1.0 with CBC is vulnerable to Beast attack. If such an attack is viable AES vs 3DES is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are actually asking whether any cipher suite is objectively worse than the others, the answer is clear:

**`TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`**. Why? Well, this cipher suite suffers from 3 "major" problems, at least one of which is remedied by any of the other cipher suites:

- **Lack of [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).** This cipher suite doesn't use any form of (EC)DHE key exchange, thus if the private RSA key is leaked (eg through a server compromise), *all* passively captured past data exchanges can be decrypted.
- **Use of CBC.** TLS has a history of having (somewhat practically exploitable) issues with its padding used for CBC, e.g. [POODLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) or with IV selection, e.g. [BEAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#BEAST_attack). Also notable here is [Lucky13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Thirteen_attack), which apparently is somewhat hard to mitigate if you want to use CBC. The CBC padding issues are  available to attackers because AES-CBC is used in a mac-then-encrypt situation where the padding is removed before the message is authenticated.
- **Use of a cipher with a small block size.** If you use a block cipher with a $n$-bit block cipher, you expect to see a collision in the CBC ciphertext after about $2^{n/2}$ blocks. With AES, this is $2^{64}$, but with 3DES this is $2^{32}$ blocks (due to its 64-bit blocksize) which gave reason for the [Sweet32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Security) attack.

You may also want to note that technically the security margin of three key 3DES is 112-bit, as opposed to AES' 128-bit, so it's worse off even there, but it's a matter of "meh, can't brute-force" vs "meh, can't brute-force".

Comment: Although breaking an individual key is impractical even with a $2^{112}$ keyspace, when a huge number of such keys are constantly being generated and used, [I wouldn't be so sure](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20151120-batchattacks.html). Specifically, `the inner loop of brute-force search is slightly cheaper than a normal AES evaluation, since there are many ways to merge work across the AES evaluations for multiple inputs`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to asking us, you can use an nmap script to evaluate the cipher suite.

```
nmap  --unprivileged -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com
```

This will connect to the server, list off the algorithms, then print a letter grade rating each cipher. It will also show the 3DES algorithm as the weakest choice in your list above (it gets a ‘C’).

I use this script all the time when checking out my servers’ security.